# MySQL update/concatenate column if NULL, using data from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a contacts table:

```
id   first_name   last_name   full_name
1    John         Doe         -null-
2    -null-       -null-      Mike Willson
3    Dany         Jean        -null-
4    Peter        -null-      -null-
```

How can i merge **first_name** and **last_name** columns to fill **full_name** column where **full_name** is **NULL**?

I would like to get results as this:

```
id   first_name   last_name   full_name
1    John         Doe         John Doe 
2    -null-      -null-       Mike Willson
3    Dany         Jean        Dany Jean
4    Peter        -null-      Peter
```

Comment: where does `mike` come from..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET full_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name)
WHERE full_name IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(first_name, last_name) IS NOT NULL
```

Will update the `full_name` if it's NULL and either `first_name` or `last_name` is not NULL.

Note that `CONCAT_WS()` will ignore NULL parameters. So if `first_name` or `last_name` is NULL, you will only get the other value without the `' '` space.

See demo on [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it this way - and it wors fine:

```
UPDATE `conacts_table`
SET `full_name` = CONCAT(IFNULL(first_name, ''), ' ', IFNULL(last_name, ''))
WHERE `full_name` IS NULL
```

Just wonder if it's the optimal way to do it?

Comment: That and a couple of TRIMs, and a NULLIF if the concatenated result is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `CONCAT()`, `COALESCE()` and `TRIM()` functions together :

```
UPDATE contacts_table
   SET full_name = TRIM(CONCAT( COALESCE(first_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(last_name,'') ))
```

without a `WHERE` condition.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ec0bb84a134a5a3dea82cd9398a89ec)</kbd>